# NuSOAP WSDL location with NGINX and PHP-FPM

Tags: php, web-services, nginx, soap

I'm trying to publish a SOAP Service (which works locally). My challenge is to get the WSDL link to point to correct location on my server.

The WSDL link is pointing to **url.com/index.php?wsdl**
I want it to point to itself: **url.com/consignor.php?wsdl**

As far as I can tell the problem is related to NGINX and php-fpm.

It looks like NuSOAP is using the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] variable to set the WSDL location, and because Laravel handles all requests through index.php $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = index.php, the same goes for PHP_SELF, while $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = consignor.php.

In my development environment all related $_SERVER variables is consignor.php, and the service works.

I've tried to override the fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME in my NGINX config, but it didn't work.

Here is my location block from NGINX config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 50M \n post_max_size=51M";
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What if the `request_uri` is `http://example.com/worm/?wsdl` ? Should it also use that?

Comment: In general, yes, because the location block mentioned is configured to serve my website/webshop. The service is a small part of the webshop.

I've tried to create a location = /consignor.php {...} block without success as well.

Comment: Then just feed the name in the script as a constant.

Comment: Could you please specify? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I appreciate your help!